# find files with more than 1 match using grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I'm wondering if there's a way to list files with more than 1 match using grep. Here's what i'm doing. I'm trying to go through a client's website and replace the last match with a string. so at the bottom of every page, he has this line:

```
<p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#808080" size="2">
```

which is followed by a footer. I need to replace it (using sed) with this line:

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

but i want to isolate the files that only have 1 instance of that first line, so i can replace them. Another solution to my problem would be to use sed on only the last match, or use sed on the last 50 lines of a file. any ideas for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `grep -c` to get a count of matches in a file:

```
grep -c '<p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#808080" size="2">' file
```

To store its output

```
cnt=$(grep -c '<p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#808080" size="2">' file)
```

Comment: this was a very simple, elegant solution for the problem. parse the data right out of the gate. this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
for a in *; do one=\`grep exit $a | wc -l\`; if [ $one = 1 ]; then echo replace in $a; fi; done
```

and in place of `echo`, do your replacement.

Comment: this is a nice solution but i chose the other answer because it was a much shorter solution and used only grep, as opposed to using multiple different tools at the same time. like wc